# Hiding div element without hiding a part of div

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I've got a problem which I have no idea how to get around of.
I use a shop script where I can only edit CSS file. 
I have a div with background-image and in there I have a normal image:

```html
<style type="text/css">
.someclassforcss img{
some:attributes;
}
.someclassforcss {
background-image:url(/link.png);
}
</style>
<div class="someclassforcss">
            <img src="/link2.png">
</div>
```

Everything's good, but I want to use media queries (or any other method) to hide background-image of div for mobile devices, but I have no idea how to make it, because media queries doesn't work for specific attributes, only for whole elements, so if I would've hided the div, my img is also hided which i don't want.

Comment: do you want to hide the whole div or just the background image (and keep the content of the div)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){
 .someclassforcss {
   background: none;
 }
}
```

Comment: what is the difference of mine?

Comment: For mobile devices 767px should be the max-width not 762px

Comment: It doesn't matter for the question context. I even could put "***px"

Answer (score 1):

You DO can change attribute regarding media dimensions.

**Your CSS:**

```
.someclassforcss {
   background-image:url(/link.png);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 762px){
  .someclassforcss {
     background-image: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the div with a media query. eg:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
 .someclassforcss {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

or if you just want to remove the background image:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
 .someclassforcss {
    background-url: none;
  }
}
```